# Marks in scintilla scrollbar?

Tags: scrollbar, scintilla

Does it possible to mark search results/breakpoints/bookmarks in scrollbar of scintilla control? Like it done in Google Chrome or JetBrains IDEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

First you have to know which lines to mark. After your search *(using scintilla search engine or your own)* you can loop call **SCI_MARKERADD** and pass those lines as arguments + the marker type you want to use.

More info:
http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_MARKERADD

Comment: I don't know why this answer is accepted as solution as it does not conform the asking. OP asks for markers in scrollbar but the solution provides markers in the margin which is definitely not the same.

Comment: because as the scintilla documentation mentions: "Markers appear in the selection margin to the left of the text."... at least with the markers Im used to working, there's no way to add them to the scrollbar in the Scintilla control. 

I assumed he was referring to the left margin by default and it seems that he was, because he marked the question as answered.